# Is there any open-source Python module for solving a vehicle routing problem with the constraints below?

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python and I try to work only with open-source interface and solver.

I would like to solve a vehicle routing problem with the following constraints:

- Heterogeneous fleet
- Not all the vehicles have to be used
- Multiple products
- Multiple Compartments
- Split deliveries
- Time Windows
- Driver breaks

Can anyone recommend a Python module for this?

Comment: Looks like you posted a new question when your other was held. You really ought to have edited the existing question, please remember that.  I hope you get an answer :-)